# Metodo setText não insere o texto corretamente dentro de um laço de repetição

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Eu criei um método que mostra um laço de repetição, e dentro dele eu fico setando o produto da variável pelo contador, como uma tabuada e tal.

Só que quando chega no TextSet, ele nao mostra os 10 textSet que era pra mostrar, e sim apenas o ultimo. Porque isso acontece e como arrumar isso?

Aqui o código:

```
public class Tabuada extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String numero;
    int valor,contador=0;

    public Tabuada() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        camponumero = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        botaomostrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        textomostra = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("TABUADA");

        jLabel2.setText("Numero");

        botaomostrar.setText("Mostrar");
        botaomostrar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                botaomostrarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        textomostra.setColumns(20);
        textomostra.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(textomostra);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(106, 106, 106)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(camponumero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 179, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(botaomostrar))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 166, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(camponumero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(botaomostrar)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 189, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void botaomostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
             numero = camponumero.getText();
             valor = Integer.parseInt(numero);



           visualiza();




    }                                            

  public void visualiza(){

     while(contador<=10){
         textomostra.setText(this.valor+" x "+this.contador+" = "+valor*contador);
         contador = contador + 1;
     }


  }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tabuada().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton botaomostrar;
    private javax.swing.JTextField camponumero;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea textomostra;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Esse código não é executável. Edite a pergunta e forneça um **[mcve]**, assim fica mais facil executar o problema e sugerir algo.

Comment: coloquei o codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só exibe a última porque o método `setText` não concatena texto caso o campo já possua um, ele simplesmente substitui. Para concatenar texto em `JTextArea`, você deve utilizar o método [`append()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append-java.lang.String-):

```
 public void visualiza(){

     while(contador<=10){
        String str = this.valor+" x "+this.contador+" = "+valor*contador;
         textomostra.append(str);
         textomostra.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
         contador = contador + 1;
     }
  }
```

Adicionei uma linha que concatena uma quebra de linha, para que a exibiçao fique correta.

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]